# How to refractor big if-else webservice dispatcher

Tags: java, web-services, architecture

## The Problem

In my webservice I have only one dispatching function that handle every call by checking the first parameters that keep the name of the function called.

## Why ?

The reason is when we update the software of our clients. We don't update obligatory the server and the client at the same time and if we generate the client from the server wsdl. The coupling is strong and the compatibility will break. Ex: if we add a function to the webservice server and update only the server exception will be thrown cause the client is not sync with the server anymore.

## Exemple

### Client

```
public class WClient {
  public WClient () {}
  public String callFunction2(){
      String[] parameters = {"function2", "blabla"};
      WServer.dispatchingFunction(parameters);
  }
}
```

### Server

```
public class WServer {

  public WServer() {}

  public String[] dispatchingFunction(String[] parameters) throws Throwable {
      String functionName = paramaters[0];
      if(functionName.equals(function1)) {};
      else if(functionName.equals(function2)) {};
      ...
      else if(functionName.equals(function15)) {};
      else //ERROR
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely need to refactor this? Could you declare the web service part as deprecated, leave it as is and add new features by adding restful APIs on the server? With restful APIs you can basically always get away with adding things without worrying about the client breaking.

Comment: I not absolutely need to refractor this but I want know good practices about this. I forgot to say that is a soap Web service, I thin u notice that. But I must stay with the soap technology for that, its maybe &amp;#224; good idea to submit the rest idea, thx